# TCP with multiple threads vs UDP for a game server

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I've been doing a lot of reading (out of curiosity) about game servers. For fast paced games (first person shooters) UDP seems to be a must.

From what I gathered, what it comes down to is what happens when packets get lost. You'll get enormous latency while TCP tries to resend/receive the lost packet and game's state at that point will be already way ahead of the client, making that packet that you waited for so long useless by the time it arrives.

Provided that you disable Nagle's algorithm, I've some trouble figuring out why something like this won't work, instead of dealing with UDP packets:

You open up multiple connections to server

```
client thread 1 <- packet 1
client thread 2 <- packet 2
client thread 3 <- packet 3
client thread 4 <- packet 4
client thread 5 <- packet 5
```

So what if something happens to packet 1 and you receive it 500ms later, you'll have packet 2 by then so it doesn't matter and client can discard it. I'm sure I'm missing some key info but I couldn't find anything on this. Something like what I'm proposing is very trivial to implement with Zeromq or another messaging library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposed technique would help somewhat (and btw it doesn't really require multiple threads, only multiple TCP connections), but it does assume that whatever was causing packet loss will only affect the packets of some of the TCP connections and not all of them.  That might not be a very reliable assumption -- since all of the TCP connections are (presumably) going through the same network path, any fault condition (or bandwidth shortage) that causes TCP stream A to drop a packet might well cause streams B through E to drop packets as well -- and then you are back to the original problem again.

Having multiple TCP streams active does allow you to work around the strict-ordering requirements of a single TCP stream (i.e. if you know the updates in data-stream B are logically independent of the updates in data-stream A, then why force a new B-update to always wait until all the previously-sent A-updates have been successfully transmitted?).  I suspect you'll still find situations where UDP works better, though.  A hybrid approach (using UDP for the low-latency data, but also a TCP stream for the more latency-tolerant or complex data) might yield a better result.